# How does putting this DE in Sturm-Liouville form help me to solve this integral problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

Consider the following question

[image: question]

I have worked out that the Eigenvalues for this DE are $\lambda_n = 4 - \frac{n^2 \pi^2}{4}$ and that the corresponding Eigenfunctions are $y_n = B \cdot Sin(n \pi)$ for some constant $B \in \mathbb{R}$.

I have also found the Sturm-Louville form of the equation, which is
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left[ e^{4x} y' \right] + e^{4x} \lambda y = 0$
$$
Assuming that my results above are correct, how am I to attempt the next part of this question?

Comment: Finding the weight for which the inner product between two eigenfunctions gives $C_n\delta_{nm}$ doesn't necessarily help you find the eigenvalues of your BVP's operator, but it will be useful when you want to solve linear PDE's. It'll also give you some insight into the structure of the spectrum via the Rayleigh quotient.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the integral
$$\int_{0}^{2}-e^{-4x}\sin\left(\lambda_nx\right)\sin\left(\lambda_mx\right)dx$$
and see what pops out.